# Sveltekit + Docker + Prisma (prisma do not seem to work)

Tags: docker, prisma, sveltekit

Anyone who can see anything off in my Dockerfile?
Prisma works well when running: pnpm run dev in ordinary Dev folder (also seems to work well via Vercel). But when running through Docker any prisma calls/requests to db do not seem to work at all.

Isn't I'm copying .env and prisma folder correctly in my Dockerfile or am I perhaps missing something else? (.env has DATABASE_URL = "postgres: .... which Prisma uses)

```
FROM node:18-alpine as builder
RUN npm install -g pnpm

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN pnpm install

COPY prisma ./prisma/

COPY .env ./

RUN npx prisma generate

COPY . .


RUN pnpm run build

FROM node:18-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/build .
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json .
COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

Comment: Can you check the container logs to see if there are any error messages? You can do this by running `docker logs <container-id>.

Comment: Most likely it's a docker networking problem. If your DB is running on localhost, you don't have access to it from your docker container by default.
A quick hack would be to use host networking instead of the default bridge.
https://docs.docker.com/network/